# To find the length of a split string in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I have split a string into an array in JAVASCRIPT using the split() method and now I want to find the length of that array. But I couldn't. Each time that I ask for the length, the answer is always 1.

```js
var name = "AlanTuring";
var splitName =[];
splitName.push(name.split(""));
var length =splitName.length;
console.log(length);
```

Comment: Here name.split is generating an array and you are pushing that array onto splitName array. SO to get length you have to do splitName[0].length

Comment: you're pushing the splitted array as one element inside splitName so you always get length as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
splitName.push(name.split(""));
```

is splitting your string, then `push`ing *the entire split array* as a single element into another array.

The result is that `splitName` will be an array of arrays, like this:

```
[
  ["A", "l", "a", "n", "T", "u", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
]
```

Try

```
var name = "AlanTuring";
var splitName = name.split("");
var length = splitName.length;
console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```js
var name = "AlanTuring";
var splitName = name.split("");
var length =splitName.length;
console.log(length);
```

Comment: You create a code snippet on SO [`code snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

`string.split("");` returns an array that you need. You need not store the result and then push it in another array. This will suffice -:

```js
    var name = "AlanTuring";
    var splitArr = name.split("");
    console.log(splitArr.length);
```

Comment: You create a code snippet on SO [`code snippet`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

If your only purpose is to get number of characters in string you can simply use [`String.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

```js
console.log("AlanTuring".length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove push. it will works.

```
const name = "AlanTuring";
const splitName = name.split("");
const length = splitName.length;
console.log(length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use String constructor function.

```
var splitName = new String(name);
```

Output like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Dont need to push. Because `push` push entire split array as a single element into the array. So it displays count 1.

```js
var name = "AlanTuring";
var splitName =[];
    splitName =name.split("");
var length =splitName.length;
console.log(length);
```